# Using admin/non-admin operations at runtime in Windows servercore container

Tags: docker, docker-container, windows-container, server-core

I am using Windows servercore container that has ContainerAdministrator and ContainerUser users.

At build-time, its easy to switch between the two users with `USER user`

However, at runtime. I also require to run operations with both elevated and non-elevated operations. I tried searching around but couldn't find a way to do this.
Both starting as:

- ContainerAdministrator - run operations as non-elevated
- ContainerUser - run operations as elevated

Comment: Have you ever managed to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Shame that no one has replied to this :(